# Https form post in javascript form with scrapy

Tags: javascript, python, html, scrapy

I am using scrapy and I want to post parameters to the following https login form:

```
<form id="loginForm" name="loginForm" action="/ax/login/loginNN.html" onsubmit="loginWidget.logIn(); loginWidget=null;" onkeypress="checkForReturn(this, event)" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="referer" value="/ax/web/nn/index.html" />
    <input type="hidden" name="encryption" value="1" />

    <div class="fakePasswordContainer">
                <input class="js-clear_field" tabindex="-1" name="fake_password" type="password">
    </div>

    <div class="input-group input-group-custom">
        <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="icon icon_user"></span></span>
        <input type="text" class="form-control lowercase" placeholder="Username" id="input1" name="8d144c359a21a05e83e9a1b56ec6a8e7" type="text" autocomplete="off" >
    </div>

    <div class="input-group input-group-custom">
        <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="icon icon_key"></span></span>
        <input id="fakeholder" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" autocomplete="off" style="display:none;">
        <input id="pContent" type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" autocomplete="off">
        <input id="pContHidden" name="420d27b4073e303b678e19767daa0f38" type="hidden" autocomplete="off" />
    </div>

    <div class="row multiple-button-container">

            <div class="col-sm-7 align-left">
                <p class="btn-inline"><a href="NewPsw.html?a3=NNSE&a4=sv&usePhrase=0">Password forgotten?</a></p>
            </div>

        <div class="col-sm-5">
            <button id="login_btn" type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-custom btn-block cta" onclick="if (loginWidget != null) return loginWidget.logIn()">Log in</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

I fail to do so and this is my spider parser:

```
def parse(self, response):
    sel = Selector(response)
    login_parameters = sel.xpath("//div/div/div/div/div/div/form[@id='loginForm']/div")
    user_param = ""
    pass_param = ""
    for parameter in login_parameters:
        param1 = parameter.xpath('input[@id="input1"]/@name').extract()
        if param1:
            user_param = param1[0]
        param2 = parameter.xpath('input[@id="pContHidden"]/@name').extract()
        if param2:
            pass_param = param2[0]
    form_data = {u'referer':u'/ax/login/startSE.html?cmpi=start-login',u'encryption': u'1',u'fake_password':,user_param:u'123456',,pass_param : u'Abcdefg'}
    url = u'https://www.ordnet.se/ax/login/loginNN.html'
    print form_data
    yield FormRequest(url, callback=self.parse2, formdata=form_data)
```

Am I missing any parameters in the post or am I doing anything else incorrectly? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It would be better if you do it with selenium. To prevent fake requests and bots usually there are hidden elements with tokens and CSRF strings which you can't easily fake.
With selenium you can sit in the driver seat and control execution of scripts or can trigger events.